# How to connect to Amazon Elasticsearch Service with Spring Data ElasticsearchTemplate?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have my Elasticsearch cluster running on Amazon Elasticsearch Service.

I was trying to find the solution how to connect my java application to that Elasticsearch cluster but I could not find any other answers than via `RestClient`.

So my question is - Is there any way how can I create `spring data ElasticSearchTemplate` which will communicate with Elasticsearch running on my AWS ?

Comment: Did you install Elasticsearch in EC2 instances yourself, or are you trying to communicate with [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-elasticsearch-service.html)?

Comment: @ChinHuang I am trying to communicate with  Amazon Elasticsearch Service.

Comment: But I would prefer the option where I can use ElasticSearchTemplate if there is any.

Comment: Amazon Elasticsearch Service allows communication only by the Elasticsearch REST API. Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2 will introduce [ElasticsearchRestTemplate using the Java High Level REST client](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-407). Because this version isn't  released at the time I write this comment, our application directly uses the [Java High Level REST client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-java).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there definitely is.  You would likely need a VPN connection or you could make ElasticSearch publicly available, but that isn't advisable.